# Return value, Ref, Out is there any difference?

Tags: c#

I am doing this,

```
public Order Add(Order order)
{
    order.thisA = GetValue1();
    // update the state of object
    return order;
}
```

Would i be any beneficial if I use Ref or Out here instead ?

Further implementation would require me to add this method,

```
public Order[] UpdateCollection(Order[] orderCollection)
{
    foreach(Order o in orderCollection)
          o = Update(o);

    return orderCollection;
}
```

Please tell me in light of best practices as well.

**Context:**

At the moment I am only returning INT id of the order but in future maybe I need to return more properties, but here is the full context,

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97778/crud-operation-class#

Comment: Without any context it is impossible to say, also as a favour to your fellow programmer, please don't call your object `object`. the code highlighting shows why

Comment: Short answer is no, you want to update the properties of 'object', not the reference to it

Comment: @Sayse I added context now with some code

Comment: take a look at this Hopefully it should answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209476/best-practice-ref-parameter-or-return-value

Comment: I've removed my downvote but your update hasn't made it much clearer, you might want to explain how your question relates to it. Even then it may become opinion based but possibly not. Is it safe to assume that `MyObject` is a value type?

Comment: @Sayse please see edit, it's just a class with properties

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case:

```
public MyObject Update(MyObject object)
{
    object.thisA = GetValue1();
    // update state of object
    return object;
}
```

You are **not** changing MyObjects reference so:

1. You **don't** need to return the object back.
2. You **don't** need to use `ref`.
3. You **don't** need to use `out`.

Using `out` is for initializing an object (You must assign a value in the function).

```
MyObject obj; // didn't assign anything
Method(out obj);

public void Method(out MyObject obj){
   obj = new MyObject(); // assigned
}
```

using `ref` is in case you might change the reference of the object inside the method:

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
Update(ref obj);

public void Update(ref MyObject obj)
{
    obj = new MyObject(); // changing the ref!!!
    obj.thisA = GetValue1();
}
```

BTW, in your case you don't need to do anything:

```
public void UpdateCollection(Order[] orderCollection)
{
    foreach(Order o in orderCollection)
          Update(o);
}

public void Update(MyObject object)
{
    object.thisA = GetValue1();
}
```

You are foreaching an array and updating the object and not the reference.

Comment: You typed out my answer pretty much, just a little faster. Upvoted! If I should be honest though, his issue is that he doesn't understand the difference between the three definitions.

Comment: @Amir would you answer be valid with collection method as well ?

Comment: Yes. A collection is a reference type like MyObject and therefore if you want to change the reference inside a method you can either return the new object or use ref.

Comment: @Mathematics - I've edited and added your example.

Answer (score 2):

You use `ref` if there is a chance that you want to change the reference instead of the object's data.

Example:

```
public void RetargetReference(ref List<string> originalList)
{
    originalList = new List<string>();
    originalList.Add("World");
}

List<string> inList = new List<string>();
inList.Add("Hello");
RetargetReference(ref inList);
```

This will change the *reference* of `inList`. It will now point to a **new** list which contains one entry "World". The list that contained "Hello" will no longer be available to you unless you have another reference to it.

`ref` parameters can be useful if you want to change parameter you passed in during the execution of the method.

`out` will be used to have the method create a new object instance *without* you being able to pass a value in!

Example:

```
public void CreateReference(out List<string> newList)
{
    newList = new List<string>();
    newList.Add("Hello World");
}

List<string> list;
CreateReference(out list);
```

After that, `list` will point to a new `List<string>` instance. Inside the method you have no access to whatever `newList` actually "points to". You will always have to create a new instance.

`out` parameters can be useful if you want your method to return more than one result. For example, the following method would return a `bool` to indicate success and two `out` parameters that contain the data:

```
public bool TrySplitString(string source, out string part1, out string part2)
{
    part1 = String.Empty;
    part2 = String.Empty;

    string[] parts = source.Split('=');
    if (parts.Length != 2)
        return false;

    part1 = parts[0];
    part2 = parts[1];
    return true;
}
```

Objects are generally passed by reference in C#, so the following method actually changes the data "outside" the method:

```
public void ChangeList(List<string> list)
{
   list.Add("World");
}

List<string> inList = new List<string>();
inList.Add("Hello");
ChangeList(inList);
```

After that, `inList` contains two entries: "Hello" and "World".

The reason why sometimes you return the object that was passed in as a parameter is that this allows so called "method chaining" where you can "write sentences" instead of "commands". You'll see that in my next example:

```
public static List<string> CreateList()
{
    return new List<string>();
}

public static List<string> AddItem(this List<string> list, string item)
{
    list.Add(item);
    return list;
}

public static List<string> DoSomethingWithList(this List<string> list)
{
    ...;

    return list;
}
```

You can use this code and write something like this:

```
List<string> list = CreateList().AddItem("Hello").DoSomethingWithList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Return `object` back may be used for create "method chaining", like this:

```
someObject.Update(MyObject object).MyObjectMethod1().MyObjectMethod2();
```

Comment: That's called "method chaining", just in case you want to update your answer :-D

Answer (score 0):

I can't really workout what you really trying to achieve. However, i will give you some basics.

In C#, arguments can be passed to parameters either by `value` or by `reference`.

If your `MyObject` is a `reference type` (eg: `class`) then it is passed to function as `reference` and hence you will end up in modifying same object. In other way, any change you make on this instance (within the function) will have a direct impact on that instance and it will continue to be true in the current execution environment.

On the other hand, if `MyObject` is a `value type` (eg: `struct`) then a copy of it will be passed to method. That is, original instance of your value type is not altered even if you modify the members within the method. This is default behavior when it comes to value type.

Now assume a scenario where you wanted to modify the original instance of value type. This can be achieved only if you pass the reference of your value type. Here comes [ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) and [out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx). Using these keyword, you can pass parameter by reference. There are differences between [ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) and [out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx), which can be learned separately. However, keeping your context in mind, the ref and out both allow the called method to modify a parameter.
`ref` means that the parameter has a value on it before going into the function. So that the function can read and or change the value within it. On the other hand, `out` means that the parameter has no official value before going into the function. The called function must initialize it before parameter goes out from function.