# Move duplicate numbers at end in integer array

Tags: c#

I want to move all duplicate numbers at the end of array like this.

{4,1,5,4,3,1,6,5}

{4,1,5,3,6,4,1,5}
also i want to know number of dups. that i will use to resize array.
here is the code i tried but this code is not compatible when i insert more than 2 dups at starting.

```
static void RemoveRepeated(ref int[] array)
    {
        int count = 0; bool flag;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            flag = true;
            for (int j = i+1; j < array.Length-1; j++)
            {
                if (array[i] == array[j] )
                {
                        int temp = array[j];
                        array[j] = array[j + 1];
                        array[j + 1] = temp;
                        if (flag)
                        {
                            count++;
                            flag = false;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        Array.Resize(ref array,array.Length-count);
    }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: At the end, you want to remove duplicate?

Comment: is order matter or you just want all duplicates at the end?

Comment: Just a question. why not `array=array.Distinct().ToArray()` ? you prefer a way without using LINQ or what ?

Comment: @aloisdg- yes i wanna remove duplicates from the array.

Comment: @AbdulRehman i just want dups at the end order doesn't matter.

Comment: @MageshKumaar i don't want to use any library class/function.and linq. Otherwise i can do directly with HashSet easily.

Comment: Why do you title your post "move duplicate numbers at end of array" but your intent is to obtain a distinct list?

Answer (score 2):

A good solution will be to use a fitting data-structure. It will not fix your algorithm but replace it. Here a `HashSet<T>` is perfect. A `HashSet<T>` remove itself all duplicate. Check the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more informations.

[Demo on .NETFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6K4peo)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var array = new int[]{ 4,1,5,4,3,1,6,5 };

        RemoveRepeated(ref array);

        foreach (var item in array)
            Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    static void RemoveRepeated(ref int[] array)
    {
        array = new HashSet<int>(array).ToArray();
    }
}
```

By the way you don't really need `ref` here. I would remove it and change `void RemoveRepeated(ref int[] array)` to `int[] RemoveRepeated(int[] array)`. See [ref parameter or return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209476/best-practice-ref-parameter-or-return-value)

Comment: This will remove the duplicats, but you forgot that he needs to count them.

Comment: @Jannik He need to count them only to resize his array. With my solution, you don't have to count it at all. You just don't need it.

Comment: Ah, okay, I thought he needed it, because he asked for it explicitly. :)

Comment: @aloisdg i don't want to use HashSet or any collection classes.

Comment: @PraveenDeewan Why do you waste your time? You are already using a collection called array.  If you just trying to prove yourself, why don't your write your code in assembler?  Or better yet start from the beginning and design your own processor so you don't have a dependency on Intel or AMD.

Comment: @Sam  sir i understand, there are many things dot net has provided already but sometimes there is some limitations to use such kind of classes. and if i write assembly code then possibly i were not asked this question.

Comment: The specific questions you asked were a) how move duplicates to the end of the array and b) how to count the number of dupes.  Presumably you want a distinct list (which you did not ask for but myself and others have been kind enough to point you in the right direction).  What limitations does .net impose and why are these limitations not specified in your question?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is equivalent to leaving only the unique elements in their original order. Here is simpler way to do this:

```
    static void RemoveRepeated(ref int[] array)
    {
        HashSet<int> seen = new HashSet<int>();
        List<int> newArray = new List<int>(array.Length);

        foreach(int x in array)
        {
            if(!seen.Contains(x))
            {
                seen.Add(x);
                newArray.Add(x);
            }
        }

        array = newArray.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an array here. You can try to (just one example) group a `List<int>` and `Count()` all groups that have more than one element. When you have the count, you can use `Distinct()` to get only the distinct elements.

In my opinion, resizing an array like this is always a very bad idea.

**Edit:**

Well, like the other answers already stated, a HashSet is a even better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] ints = {4,1,5,4,3,1,6,5};

        var query = ints.GroupBy(x => x).OrderBy(x => x.Count()).Select(x => x);


        // print ordered array showing dupes are last
        query.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Key.ToString()));

        // Get number of dupes
        int dupeCount = query.Where(x => x.Count() > 1).Count();

        // put unique items into a new array
        var newArray = query.Where(x => x.Count() == 1).Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();

        // put distinct items into an array
        var distinctArray = ints.Distinct().ToArray();

        Console.ReadKey();   
    }
}
```

Edit:  Added distinct elements

Comment: Please don't use `.ToList().ForEach()`. [“foreach” vs “ForEach”](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).

Comment: For the purpose it was used its fine but thanx for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the duplicates to the end of array (but preserve order) you can do this:

```
static void RemoveRepeated(ref int[] array)
{
    var lookup = array.ToLookup(x => x);
    var maxdupes = lookup.Select(x => x.Count()).Max();

    var reordered =
        Enumerable
            .Range(0, maxdupes)
            .SelectMany(x => lookup.SelectMany(y => y.Skip(x).Take(1)))
            .ToArray();

    Array.Copy(reordered, array, reordered.Length);
}
```

This would turn `{ 4, 1, 5, 4, 3, 1, 6, 5 }` into `{ 4, 1, 5, 3, 6, 4, 1, 5 }`

You can easily get the number of duplicates by doing this:

```
lookup
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Value = x.Key,
        Count = x.Count(),
    });
```

This returns:

```
4 2 
1 2 
5 2 
3 1 
6 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[] { 4, 1, 5, 4, 3, 1, 6, 5 };
        RemoveRepeated(ref arr);
        foreach (int i in arr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void RemoveRepeated(ref int[] array)
    {
        int count =0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < array.Length; j++)
            {
                if (array[i] == array[j])
                {
                    int temp = array[j];
                    count++;
                    for (int k = j; k < array.Length-1; k++)
                    {
                        array[k] = array[k + 1];
                    }
                    array[array.Length - 1] = temp;
                    j = array.Length;
                }
            }
        }
        Array.Resize(ref array, array.Length - count);
    }
}
```